# join objects in NSArray

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

i have an array like this:

```
NSArray *arr = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"1",@"2",@"3",@"4",@"5",@"6",nil];
```

how i can join the first element with the second and the third with the fourth and so on?

Comment: i sory i am new here but how i do that .and sorry of my english

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I understand, it should result into `@"12",@"34",@"56"`

```
NSArray *arr = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"1",@"2",@"3",@"4",@"5",@"6",nil];

NSMutableArray *array2 = [NSMutableArray array];
[arr enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(NSString *string1, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    if (idx > 0 && idx %2 == 1) {
        NSString  *string0 = [arr objectAtIndex:idx-1];
        [array2 addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", string0, string1]];

    }
}];

NSLog(@"%@", array2);
```

result:

```
(
    12,
    34,
    56
)
```

Comment: So please mark it as accepted by clicking the tick symbol (you should do so on ur other questions too)

Comment: :) you don't have to report it as a comment. just click the tick. Even saying thank you is not needed on Stackoverflow. just be a good citizen and take part in the reputation system (btw: for accepting answers you also get 2 points). You just passed 15 points, now u can also vote good answers and question up. Do so, [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#reputation) is what drives stackoverflow.